# Observable object not fully initialized before accessed

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

So basically, I'm trying to access a param from the data my Observable returns, which is the result of an Http call, but the param I want to access, `someProperty` is not available since the object is only fully initialized after the method is call.
A console log in `doSomething` still prints out the object, but `someProperty` only shows up a while after `oncomplete` event.

So I want to ask what is the best way to detect if my observable object data has fully initialized.

My code is something as below.

```js
export interface Result {
    anotherProperty: string;
    someProperty: any;
}

...

data: Result = [];

...

doSomething(){
    console.log(this.data[0]);
    //for (const result of this.data) {doMoreThing(result.someProperty);}
    setTimeout(() => { console.log(this.data[0]); }, 500);
}

this.myService.requestFromServer(...).subscribe((resp) => {
   this.data = resp.data;
   doSomething();
})
```

Result of console.log

```
{anotherProperty: 'dummy'}
{anotherProperty: 'dummy', someProperty: 'dummy'}
```

Comment: "So I want to ask what is the best way to detect if my observable object data has fully initialized." Depends on what you want to do with the data.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't get the point here, could you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for us? A [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) maybe?

Comment: @lealceldeiro I agree with you. Would appreciate a demo from the OP.

Comment: I can add a demo, but I doubt I would be able to reproduce as I suspect it's due to the Future I use to return the result in my backend. There is not much more to the code than this.

Answer (score 0):

You are indeed correct when you mention that the response, `resp` from `requestFromServer()` will take some time before it is returned, because HTTP requests are asynchronous.

In your case, it is perfectly normal for the `console.log()` statement to take some time to appear. `data` will be assigned with the reference from `resp` as long as it is handled within that `subscribe()` block.

If you really want to know when the observable value has been returned, I guess you can add a `console.log()` statement on the first line within `subscribe()`?

```
this.myService.requestFromServer(...).subscribe(resp => {
  console.log(resp);
  this.data = resp.data;
  // do the rest
}, error => {
  console.log(error);
}, () => {
  // on complete
  console.log(this.data);
});
```

Comment: Well, I don't get it. If `this.data` is being assigned inside the `subscribe` and the call to `doSomething` is inside the `subscribe` too (next line), how is possible that when `doSomething` is called, `this.data` does not has the correct value?

Comment: That is what puzzles me, `this.data` only has correct value only a while after oncomplete, and only 1 of my params, the one I need, is not initialized fully at the start! If I set a like 200 ms delay then console log again, I get my full object, but I don't want to add an arbitrary delay.

Comment: I'm sorry..! I am getting confused here. Is there an initial reference assigned to `this.data` prior to the above http request?

Comment: No, there is no reference prior to that. I've updated the code a little bit if you want to see more details.

Comment: @Sylph I see.. Hmm.. In that case, do you want to try print `this.data` on the `complete` callback, instead of the `next` callback? I have edited my code